# Different in and out animations for text in After Effects

Tags: after-effects

I can not figure out how to make text animate in using one style (for example, slide in based on characters) and later animate the same text out using a different style (like, slide out based on words). Animation based on characters/words can not be automated.

The only way I can think of how to do this is by creating 2 layers. But in case I need to change the text, I would need to change it twice. Are there any other ways to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add more than one selector to a text animator. Selector 1 can control the slide in, twirl down the **Animator>Range selector>Advanced** properties and look for the control called **Based On**, and set that to character.

To have a slide-on you would add an offset to the position, and then change the selector so that it progressively de-selects the text. The best way is to set the start and end to 0% and 100% respectively, and the add keyframes to the **offset** property, starting at 0 and ramping down to -100%.

Now hit the Add button next to the Animator and choose **Selector>Range** to add another selector to it. Make sure that it is selecting none of the text to start with. Change the **Based On** property of this selector to **words**. You can change the way the two selectors interact with the **Mode** control, this changes whether the selection properties add together, intersect, subtract and so on. Using the **Add* mode should work for you. With this selector you would keyframe it so that it progressively selects the words in the text when you want it to slide out. Use the same technique as the first selector, but with the keyframes reversed.

This will make the slide go back to where it came from, you might want it to continue in the same direction. To do this you would add another animator with a different offset, rather than just a selector. You can add as many independant animators to a text layer as you like.